# Populating fields in a custom tableView cell from data defined in a popover/popup

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview, uistoryboardsegue

On the settings VC of my app I have a tableview with 5 different custom cells. The cell I’m needing some help with sets a default start and end time. This is accomplished using a popover/popup with a date/time control which is opened using a segue. This cell contains 2 buttons (start and end) and 2 fields (start and end). When one of the buttons is tapped the corresponding popover/popup is displayed. The user then defines the desired time and taps a done button. I’m using a protocol/delegate method to pass the time strings from the popover/popup. This currently works, with one exception. I want the newly defined time to populate the corresponding start or end field in he cell. My thought is to move all of this code into the custom tableViewCell where I have full access to the fields but I can’t seem to make that work. Moving the prepare(for segue: to the cell file isn’t recognized. Is there a way to perform this segue from the custom cell? Or does anybody have thoughts on populating the fields using my current setup? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
// All of this code is in the tableView controller except the last part where noted

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "quote_Presets_StartTime" // # 2
        {
            let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: K.StoryboardID.date_Picker_SB, bundle: nil)
            var popupVC : Date_Popup_VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: K.StoryboardID.date_Popup_VC) as! Date_Popup_VC
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popupVC)
            
            let deviceName = UIDevice().type
            let deviceString: String = ("\(deviceName)")
            
            if deviceString.contains(K.theDevice.iPad)
            {
                popupVC = segue.destination as! Date_Popup_VC
                
                if ModelData.isInline() // Wheel
                {
                    popupVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: 300)
                    
                } else { // Inline
                    
                    popupVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 350, height: 150)
                }
                
                navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
                
            } else if deviceString.contains(K.theDevice.iPhone) {
                
                present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = false
            }
            
            popupVC.theBtn = 2
            
            let formattedTime = ModelData.formattedTime_Read(time_Db: new_Start_Time)
            popupVC.theDate = formattedTime
            
            popupVC.timeStart_Delegate = self
            
        } else if segue.identifier == "quote_Presets_EndTime" { // # 3
            let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: K.StoryboardID.date_Picker_SB, bundle: nil)
            var popupVC : Date_Popup_VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: K.StoryboardID.date_Popup_VC) as! Date_Popup_VC
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popupVC)
            
            let deviceName = UIDevice().type
            let deviceString: String = ("\(deviceName)")
            
            if deviceString.contains(K.theDevice.iPad)
            {
                popupVC = segue.destination as! Date_Popup_VC
                
                if ModelData.isInline() // Wheel
                {
                    popupVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: 300)
                    
                } else { // Inline
                    
                    popupVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 350, height: 150)
                }
                
                navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
                
            } else if deviceString.contains(K.theDevice.iPhone) {
                
                present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = false
            }
            
            popupVC.theBtn = 3
            
            let formattedTime = ModelData.formattedTime_Read(time_Db: new_End_Time)
            popupVC.theDate = formattedTime
            
            popupVC.timeEnd_Delegate = self
        }
    }

// Executed from the cellForRowAt code
    @objc
    func setTheTimes(sender: UIButton)
    {
        switch sender.tag
        {
        case 0:
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "quote_Presets_StartTime", sender: Any?.self)
            
        case 1:
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "quote_Presets_EndTime", sender: Any?.self)
            
        default: break
        }
    }

extension Quote_Presets_VC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 10
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        // cell_05 Time
        let cell_05 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.ReuseIdentifier.defaultTime_Cell, for: indexPath) as! DefaultTime_Cell
        cell_05.backgroundColor = Theme.current.darkAccentColor
        cell_05.selectionStyle = .none
        
        cell_05.delegate = self as SaveData_Time
        
        cell_05.label_Outlet.labelTextColorOnly_Attributes(txt: K.Titles.defaultStartEnd, txtWgt: .regular)
        cell_05.labelStart_Outlet.labelTextColorOnly_Attributes(txt: K.Titles.start, txtWgt: .regular)
        cell_05.labelEnd_Outlet.labelTextColorOnly_Attributes(txt: K.Titles.end, txtWgt: .regular)
        
        cell_05.startBtn_Outlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setTheTimes), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell_05.endButton_Outlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setTheTimes), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        cell_05.fldStart_Outlet.textField_Simple(text: ModelData.timeConversionTo_12(time24: new_Start_Time))
        cell_05.fldEnd_Outlet.textField_Simple(text: ModelData.timeConversionTo_12(time24: new_End_Time))
        
        switch indexPath.row
        {
        case 9: // Time
            cell_05.fldStart_Outlet.tag = 0
            cell_05.fldEnd_Outlet.tag = 1
            
            cell_05.startBtn_Outlet.tag = 0
            cell_05.endButton_Outlet.tag = 1
            
            return cell_05
            
        default: break
        }
        
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

// These are the delegates for the protocol to pass the time string
extension Quote_Presets_VC: TimeStart_DatePopupDelegate, TimeEnd_DatePopupDelegate
{
    func saveTimeStart(value: String)
    {
        var originalValue: String = ""
        for theValue in presetsArray
        {
            originalValue = theValue.start_Time
        }

        let formattedValue = ModelData.timeConversionTo_24(time12: value)

        if formattedValue != originalValue
        {
            new_Start_Time = value
            save_Array_Quote[6] = K.AppFacing_Titles.true_

        } else {

            save_Array_Quote[6] = K.AppFacing_Titles.false_
        }

        setSaveBtn_QuotePresets()
    }

    func clearTimeStart(value: String)
    {
        // startFld_Outlet.text = value
    }

    func saveTimeEnd(value: String)
    {
        var originalValue: String = ""
        for theValue in presetsArray
        {
            originalValue = theValue.end_Time
        }

        let formattedValue = ModelData.timeConversionTo_24(time12: value)

        if formattedValue != originalValue
        {
            new_End_Time = value
            save_Array_Quote[7] = K.AppFacing_Titles.true_

        } else {

            save_Array_Quote[7] = K.AppFacing_Titles.false_
        }

        setSaveBtn_QuotePresets()
    }

    func clearTimeEnd(value: String)
    {
        // endFld_Outlet.text = value
    }
}

// The code below is the current tableview cell code
protocol SaveData_Time: AnyObject
{
    func setSaveBtn_QuotePresets()
}

class DefaultTime_Cell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var label_Outlet: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelStart_Outlet: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var fldStart_Outlet: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var fldEnd_Outlet: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelEnd_Outlet: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var startFldHgt_Constraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var startBtn_Outlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var endButton_Outlet: UIButton!
    
    weak var delegate: SaveData_Time?
    
    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
    {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func startBtn_Tapped(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        // This throws an error that cannot find performSegue in scope
        //performSegue(withIdentifier: "quote_Presets_StartTime", sender: Any?.self)
    }
    
    @IBAction func endBtn_Tapped(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        // This throws an error that cannot find performSegue in scope
        //performSegue(withIdentifier: "quote_Presets_EndTime", sender: Any?.self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't convert your dates into strings until you need to. Pass `Date` values around instead.

And, to answer your question about moving more logic into your cell, don't do that. Keep your views simple.

I'd just add two closures to your DateCell to indicate if a button was tapped:

```
class DateCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var startDateButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var endDateButton: UIButton!

    var didTapStart: () -> Void = {}
    var didTapEnd: () -> Void = {}

    @IBAction func didSelectStart(_ sender: UIButton) {
        didTapStart()
    }

    @IBAction func didSelectEnd(_ sender: UIButton) {
        didTapEnd()
    }
}
```

In your date editor you can use a delegate or a closure to indicate that the date changed. I'll use a closure here:

```
class DateEditor: UIViewController {

    var dateDidChange: (Date) -> Void = { _ in }

    // ...
}
```

I'm not a fan of segues, but if you really want to use one, then create two segues, one for editing a start date and one for editing an end date:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell,
        let row = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)?.row,
        let vc = segue.destination as? DateEditor else { return }

    if segue.identifier == "editStartDate" {
        vc.date = dates[row].start
    } else {
        vc.date = dates[row].end
    }

    vc.dateDidChange = { [weak self] date in
        if segue.identifier == "editStartDate" {
            self?.dates[row].start = date
        } else {
            self?.dates[row].end = date
        }
        self?.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

Whenever one of the buttons was tapped, just trigger the segue:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DateCell", for: indexPath) as! DateCell

    cell.startDateButton.setTitle(
        DateFormatter.awesome.string(from: self.dates[indexPath.row].start),
        for: .normal
    )
    cell.endDateButton.setTitle(
        DateFormatter.awesome.string(from: self.dates[indexPath.row].end),
        for: .normal
    )

    cell.didTapStart = { [weak self] in
        self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "editStartDate", sender: cell)
    }

    cell.didTapEnd = { [weak self] in
        self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "editEndDate", sender: cell)
    }
    return cell
}
```

This is what I used for formatting dates:

```
extension DateFormatter {
    static let awesome: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .short
        formatter.timeStyle = .medium
        return formatter

    }()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer @Rob. Much appreciated. It’ll take me a bit to digest the information.